# How to parse redirect URL from oauth authorization flow with html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, oauth-2.0, strava

I would like to know how to do the following:

I have a HTML page with the following code:

```
<body>
    <div id="login">
        <a href="https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5500&approval_prompt=force"><img src="/images/btn_strava_connectwith_light.png"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

This sends me to a strava authorization page. When I authorize then I'm redirected to my localhost with the following URL:

http://localhost:5500/?state=&code=a43ddsdfasfsadf&scope=

If understand the authorization flow properly, then I need to request a token with the code from the URL. But:

I use javascript/html. How do I retrieve the code from the URL, and how can I redirect back to localhost without the parameters?

Thanks.

Comment: If I assume that the redirected url is correct.
I will try to do like this.
`var url = window.location.href;
url = url.split('?')[1];
url = url.split['&'][1];
var code = url.split['='][1];
console.log(code);`

Comment: thanks. How do I make sure that this piece of code is fired once the redirection is done? Can I add an eventlistener or some sort?

Comment: btw what is your backend framework?

Comment: I have no backend framework. Trying to learn javascript :)